# How can I create a "high score list" on a txt file which stores top 10 scores and names of the players who scored them?

Tags: java

I need to make high score list in a txt file. In the first game, the txt file should be empty as it is the first game. After the first game, the score list must be updated each time with the player's name and the player's score. The list should of course be ordered from high to low according to player's score. After 10 games, the last ones should be removed and only 10 should remain in the list.

I am trying to do this but every time my txt file is stays empty. How can I fix this issue?

My HighScore class:

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class HighScore {

    public class HighScoreEntry {
        private String name;
        private int score;

        public HighScoreEntry(String name, int score) {
            this.name = name;
            this.score = score;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public int getScore() {
            return score;
        }
    }

    public void writeHighScores(HighScoreEntry[] highScores) {
        Formatter f = null;
        FileWriter fw = null;
        try {
            fw = new FileWriter("highscores.txt",true);
            f = new Formatter(fw);
            for (int i = 0; i < highScores.length; i++) {
                f.format("%s:%d%n", highScores[i].getName(), highScores[i].getScore());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred while writing the high scores file.");
        } finally {
            if (f != null) {
                f.close();
            }
        }
    }
    
    public HighScoreEntry[] readHighScores() {
        HighScoreEntry[] highScores = new HighScoreEntry[10];
    
        // Initialize the high scores array with default values
        for (int i = 0; i < highScores.length; i++) {
            highScores[i] = new HighScoreEntry("", 0);
        }
        
        Scanner reader = null;

        try {
            reader = new Scanner(Paths.get("highscores.txt"));
            int i = 0;
            while (reader.hasNextLine() && i < 10) {
                String line = reader.nextLine();
                String[] parts = line.split(":");
                String name = parts[0];
                int score = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
                highScores[i] = new HighScoreEntry(name, score);
                i++;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred while reading the high scores file.");
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }
        }
    
        return highScores;
    }

    public void updateHighScores(String name, int score) {
        System.out.println("Updating high scores with name " + name + " and score " + score);
        // Write the player's score and name to the high scores file
        writeHighScores(new HighScoreEntry[] {new HighScoreEntry(name, score)});
        
        // Read the high scores from the file
        HighScoreEntry[] highScores = readHighScores();
        
        // Sort the high scores
        sortHighScores(highScores);
    }    

    private void sortHighScores(HighScoreEntry[] highScores) {
        for (int i = 0; i < highScores.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < highScores.length; j++) {
                if (highScores[i].getScore() < highScores[j].getScore()) {
                    HighScoreEntry temp = highScores[i];
                    highScores[i] = highScores[j];
                    highScores[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My calling method in Game class:

```
HighScore highScore = new HighScore();
highScore.updateHighScores(user, playerPoints);
```

I just have to use them. I can't use anything other than these.

Answer (score 0):

The Formatter class returns a formatted string, but you're not capturing the return value of your `format` call, nor are you writing the resulting string to your FileWriter.

It should look something like this:

```
String result = f.format("%s:%d%n", highScores[i].getName(), highScores[i].getScore());
fw.write(string);
```

Give or take a newline.

Comment: I did but it didn't work. The file is still empty.

Comment: Then you should check the `result` string to see if it has anything in it.  Ordinary troubleshooting techniques would seem to apply here.

Comment: Also, I note that you're only closing your file if an exception is thrown.  You should probably close the file in all cases.  Some file system operations will not write anything unless you close the file.